# How to detect if the user is booting from microSD versus an external USB drive (e.g. SSD)?

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, sd-card, hard-drive

I am writing a bash script and I really want a way to detect if the user has booted from a microSD card versus an external SSD drive connected via USB. Ideally, this should work with any PI3/4. I am not that familiar with how linux drives are named/labelled. Currently, I am booting my Pi from USB SSD on my Pi4, and lsblk, reports that sda1 contains the firmware, and sda2 the main partition. Can I assume that sda will always be an external USB drive, or will microSD cards use sda as well? If not, what is the best way to tell them apart? Ideally, I would prefer to use a built-in Linux command to establish this (if possible) so my script doesn't need to install any new packages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC SD card in Pi slot is always /dev/mmcblk* and USB connected drive is /dev/sd* (not necessarily sda). SD card in USB SD card reader will also show up as /dev/sd*. Look at drive mounted on /boot with e.g. lsblk

Comment: Why does it matter? What can you possibly do that's useful with that info?

Answer (score 1):

How generic does your script need to be? Are you going to support non-standard partition configurations, encrypted partitions, overlays, LVM and such? If not, you can trivially run

```
`mount | grep 'on / '| cut -d' ' -f1`
```

This will substitute to `/dev/mmcblk0p2` (in general, `/dev/mmcblk0pX`) if you boot from the built-in SD card reader, or `/dev/sda2` (in general, `/dev/sdXY`) if you boot from a USB storage, be it an SD card in a USB card reader, an SSD or an HDD. I think the current Pi bootloader will [fail](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/118774/33476) to boot from anything but `sda` anyway.

You can do the same with `lsblk` if you prefer:

```
`lsblk -o pkname,mountpoint | egrep '/$' | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

This returns either `mmcblk0` or `sda`, which is perhaps easier to parse.