# Raspberry Pi 4 not booting from USB when multiple ports are used

Tags: boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 which boots from an SSD. However, if I plug in another USB-Storage and reboot the Pi it doesn't boot anymore. Only if I unplug the additional storage it boots again from the SSD. Do you know what could be the reason for this? I attach the SSD on a SuperSpeed (blue) USB-Port and the storage on a usual one.

Comment: most usb related issues stem from insufficient current.  consider a separate powered hub in between or a beefier power supply

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xfs disk that always takes precedence over the actual boot/root ssd?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118774/how-to-cope-with-an-over-eager-xfs-disk-that-always-takes-precedence-over-the-ac) Seems to be a long-lasting bootloader issue.

Comment: I have a 30 Watt power supply because of the multiple disks I intentionally took a stronger one. @Dimitry thanks for linking the question. I'll try adding the storage-data over a hub.

Answer (score 1):

Consider booting from an SD card, while keeping your root FS on the SSD. You'll waste an SD card for that, sure, but you'll get a stable boot order no matter how many USB devices you have. Once the kernel boots, it will be able to use the partition UUID to find the right root device.